# How to implement "email_user" method in custom user model?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Trying to use django-registration module with custom user model that extends `AbstractBaseUser`.

This is a form, I use for the registration:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class UserCreateForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2")
        model = get_user_model()
```

This is the view:

```
class Register(RegistrationView):
    form_class = forms.UserCreateForm
```

This is my registration url:

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.Register.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
```

**Edit:**

Django does not send confirmation email, and browser throws an error

```
'User' object has no attribute 'email_user'
```

**Edit:**

I understand I have to implement email_user method in my custom user model. How can I do this?

Comment: Just search for that function in the `registration` package and see if you can copy it over

Answer (score 3):

I just needed to add email_user method to my custom user model

```
    def email_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
    send_mail(
        '{}'.format(args[0]),
        '{}'.format(args[1]),
        '{}'.format(args[2]),
        [self.email],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the [`email_user` from the Django AbstractUser class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/656192c2c96bb955a399d92f381e38fe2254fe17/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L400-L402).

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.core.mail import send_mail

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```